# setting last child in dax tabular

Tags: cube, dax, tabular

```
Balance:=CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Local]), 'select'[select Type]= "ACTION")
```

In Multidiemnsional model I could just select Aggregate Function as Last Child in the properties, but I what should do in the tabular in order to get the last child?
Or If I have to write a dax formula what should I add from formula above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a continuous date table, the equivalent in DAX to LastChild is

```
CALCULATE ([Measure], LASTDATE(DateTable[Date]))
```

If you don't have a continuous date table (i.e. you're using a degenerative date dimension, etc.) you'd use

```
CALCULATE ([Measure], LASTNONBLANK(TableWithDate[Date], [Measure]))
```

UPDATE: With DAX, it's almost always better to create intermediate measures to build up to your final measure for reuse, maintainability, debugging, etc.

So first just use your existing Balance measure

```
Balance:=CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Local]), 'select'[select Type]= "ACTION")
```

Then do

```
LastBalance:=CALCULATE([Balance], LASTNONBLANK(CalendarMonth[MonthKey], [Balance]) )
```

Comment: Balance: =CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[Local]), 'select'[select Type]= "ACTION", LASTNONBLANK( CalendarMonth[MonthKey], SUM(Fact[Local]), 'select'[select Type]= "ACTION")) So I made that formula butt it gives me the too many arguments error,...how can i fix it?

Comment: If I use that formula nothing happens. Don't i have to put SUM(Fact[Local]), 'select'[select Type]= "ACTION" this formula to make result of last of those part?

Comment: First, what do you mean, "nothing happens?" And second, no you do not. That is what I mean by intermediate measures.

Comment: Balance = intermediate measure. Everytime you use the Balance measure, the VertiPaq engine will go and pull the "base" measure for its calculation. Basically it does that substititution for you.

Comment: So say for a given context, Balance = 100. Then if I had a measure that said [DoubledBalance]=[Balance]*2, it will return 200.

Comment: what I meant was if i type the formula that you gave me, it does not gives me any error, but its just showing formula in measurement column, and I can't use it for measurement

Comment: oh my bad the formaula works but gives me the error that 'balance' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Do you have any idea? (Thank you so much for helping me)

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of how you're using these measures? It's hard to tell you what needs to be fixed since I can't really see how you're using the measures I've provided.

Comment: oh, i have to use that lastnonblank filters where select type= "ACTION" because I am using for Current, and Actual Balance, Do you have any Idea to put filter inside of the lastnonblank function?